# Image folder on the root

Tags: sitefinity

I have an image folder on the root of sitefinity project that I want access to but I keep getting a 404 error? Is sitefinity blocking this folder do I need to add some setting in the web.config to access this folder?

Comment: Do you want to *browse* the folder or are you trying to access a file in that folder? What's the file extension?

Comment: the files are .jpg I like like to be able to use the relative path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The /images route is normally reserved for the images in the Sitefinity libraries.

So if your folder is called images and is on the root, it is likely that sitefinity tries to find the image you request from a library and since it does not exist there - there is 404.

Best way to go is to rename your folder to something else, e.g. /assets/images

Comment: Any idea on this one  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66601104/programmatically-set-documents-access